# Ubuntu Window Manager Not starting after Upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04 (logs attached)

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, xorg, 19.04, mate

two days ago, I updated my Ubuntu System from 17.10 to 18.04. And despite being actually too late, everything went almost without any issue (only minor things I could fix quickly). Afterwards I run apt-get update/upgrade to bring everything up-to-date, also without issues.

Happy with that result, I decided yesterday to update further. I set the update mode from lts to normal and run do-release-upgrade again. I expected the system to upgrade to 18.10 first but it did directly an upgrade to 19.04. Everything run through smoothly but after reboot the system is not usable.

The Mate booting screen is shown properly. Afterwards both screens show a new background, and an almost empty panel, which is blinking every few seconds. I can click right on the desktop, but there are no helpful actions. Keyboard commands are not recognized, with the exception of Alt+Ctrl+F1 and similar.

It looks like this after start: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10_RixZrn3PysInUmTkHUoTu5KGBurRrL

This is the shown error message: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10a5W-1BsQUREw62Z2aCKv4HupHzAykAT

I used the terminal session to look at some log files in /var/log. On the console with really low resolution and without scrolling ability (using less instead), I had really problems to find anything helpful. Especially, as there are ten-thousands of lines in the relevant time frame.

I tried to boot in recovery mode, choosing the failsafeX Option. But this way the screens remained black with a blinking cursor.

I am thinking about booting with a live cd and checking the log files in a more comfortable environment. **What would be the first things/files to look for/at?**

Thanks for your time and eventual help,

McMatt

PS: As suggested, I executed journalctl and got this output: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1an9B-ilmA01Vm9Gr7TbEc50QjALGVokx
I am a bit lost in there, none of the errors sticks out as critical. Please let me know, if you have found something that might be causing the startup issue.

Comment: When you say Ctrl+Alt+F1 works are you saying you can log into a terminal session? If so try `journalctl` to look for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes to your question, but as I have already booted the live cd, I do it from here. I mounted the partition containing the log files and executed: journalctl --directory=/mnt/sda2/var/log/journal/ --since="2019-09-19 12:00:00" >> /tmp/journal.txt. (I did start the system once before switching to the live cd to generate fresh log files). I hope that I can attach the file here somehow.

Comment: Here is the result of the comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1an9B-ilmA01Vm9Gr7TbEc50QjALGVokx

Comment: I added a video of the final situation after startup: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10_RixZrn3PysInUmTkHUoTu5KGBurRrL/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: This is error message that shows up: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10a5W-1BsQUREw62Z2aCKv4HupHzAykAT/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but in my experience, the easiest, fastest, and most reliable way to fix such a situation is a clean reinstall of the newest Ubuntu version. Of course this will involve backing up your home directory (unless you have a separate`/home` partition) and possibly some other files that you modified in the system. Nevertheless, this will probably be quicker then trying to figure out what went wrong and fixing it. And yield a cleaner result.

Comment: Hi Malte, thanks for your message . I have /home on a separate partition, this would be fine. But I have set up Raid, scheduled backups, mate, key shortcuts, and things I will probably remember when they do not work after the fresh install. I know this took quite some time and sweat. Wouldn't that all be lost?

Comment: From the error log, I saw this: `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache` Try this command to see if it works?

Comment: @McMatt Yes indeed, all of that would be lost. I personally have a "log file" where I summarize all changes that I did to the system in the past. When I make a fresh install of a system, I go through that log file and simply apply those changes again in the new system. Sure it's a bit of work, but not that much (at least in my case), and more often than not I notice that I don't need 50% of the changes I did on my last system any more. ;-) It helps me to keep a clean system and avoid the hassle of fixing difficult-to-pinpoint bugs that occured during a system upgrade. Matter of taste, perhaps.